# Using Qt ItemDelegate

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use QStyledItemDelegate in order to display path in my list view, the following is the reason why I'm doing it, having path:

```
C:\some_path\another_path\and_another_path\and_filnally_some_file.txt
```

and listView which has width which is not wide enough to display full path, I'm trying to modify the path string to:

```
C:\...\and_another_path\and_filnally_some_file.txt
```

and by doing so this will fit into view, but which fnc do I need to reimplement in my delegate in order to achieve that? (I'm mean to send this modified string to the view)
Another modification to the string I'm trying to do is to bolden name of the file and grey out rest of the path, and again this needs to be done in delegate but in which function? paint?

Comment: yes, you have to reimplement `paint` function

Comment: #Lol4t0 but I cannot see anywhere in paint functions arguments reference to this string I'm trying to modify. I mean the data will be returned by model I suppose but how to catch it?

Comment: You are given `const QModelIndex & index` to get the data

Comment: @Lol4t0 ok, thanks, got it. Will try to play with this for a while.

Answer (score 1):

From [`QStyledItemDelegate` documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qstyleditemdelegate.html) :

**Subclassing QStyledItemDelegate**

If the delegate does not support painting of the data types you need or you want to customize the drawing of items, you need to subclass QStyledItemDelegate, and reimplement `paint()` and possibly `sizeHint()`. The `paint()` function is called individually for each item, and with `sizeHint()`, you can specify the hint for each of them.

I suggest reimplementing both.